# Kafka consumer not connecting to remote host

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

In the past few days i've been learning about kafka and doing smalls tests and stuff.

I could already consume messages succesfuly in my localhost, even from another pc within the same network. But now that i'm trying to connect to a remote server (it's actually the same pc, and same broker and topic, i just have two internet service providers so i just switched in order to try with the public ip), i don't receive any messages. Also, i get this in the console:

```
[main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=0a396775-94e2-46a0-a6bf-08f0d848ffc9] Connection with /xxx.xx.xxx.xxx disconnected
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.finishConnect(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.finishConnect(KafkaChannel.java:216)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:531)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:483)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:539)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:262)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:233)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:212)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:249)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:326)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1251)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1220)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1159)
    at com.okta.javakafka.kafkajava.SimpleConsumer.main(SimpleConsumer.java:39)
```

I tried a couple of pinging tests and the connection was succesful. So maybe i'm missing something that's different in the case of a remote kafka connection?

If someone could help, i'd appreciate it a lot

************** **EDIT** ****************************

listeners on my server.properties:

listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.101:9092 (local ip)

advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://200.x.xxx.xxx:9092 (public ip)

Comment: Ping does not do port checks... Please show your server.properties and consumer properties or read https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: @cricket_007 After watching a tutorial and reading more i tried adding the listeners and advertised.listeners lines, but still not able to produce or consume messages to the broker

Comment: Listeners should always be 0.0.0.0, otherwise you're limiting connections to interfaces only on that exact ip

Comment: @cricket_007 I changed the first listener to 0.0.0.0:29092, still can't read it from other network. Maybe I'm missing something in the commands i'm using? i'm doing it like this: bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --bootstrap-server 200.X.X.X:9092 --topic remotetopic

Comment: Why are you trying to connect to `:9092` if the listener is on `:29092`? Also, you can describe a topic using zookeeper instead

Comment: @cricket_007 because the advertised listener is on 9092. The link you provided showed an example where the public IP was set on 9092, and the internal one was set at 29092.. Anyways I think the ports i'm trying to access are closed. I'm trying to open them now

Comment: The listeners define the open ports. If you don't define the port in the listeners, it will not be open, so you cannot advertise it.